# AWS CLI tools - cannot download recursively from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a following structure on S3:

```
bucket:
   - dir_test
       - dir_a
           - dir
               - file
           - file_2
           - file_2
           - file_n
       - dir_b
           - dir
                - file
           - file_2
           - file_2
           - file_n
```

I want to download a whole content of dir_test to my working directory from a shell script:

```
source_path="s3://bucket/dir_test/"
target_path="."
aws s3 cp "$source_path" "$target_path" --recursive
```

Everything is downloaded fine, however aws reports Errno 21:

```
download failed: s3://bucket/dir_test/dir_a/dir/ to dir_a/dir/ [Errno 21] Is a directory: u'/my-wd/dir_a/dir/'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the `aws s3 sync` command -- it does a recursive copy by default and could be more useful for certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

Your copy command looks correct, but that error doesn't make sense -- S3 doesn't actually have directories, so it should never attempt to "download" an empty directory. Directories are created locally as a side-effect of downloading files (the S3 file is actually named "foo/bar/baz.txt" and the CLI tool is translating that into "baz.txt" in the "bar" dir in the "foo" dir).

I wonder if you have something strange, like a *file* named "dir/"? Or a file with an empty name? Try `aws s3 ls s3://bucket/dir_test/dir_a/dir/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out [mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) tool too:

`mc cp  https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketName/... localdir`

The `...` in the command indicates recursive operation